# Running Spark-Scala Code without using Eclipse or IntelliJ and Maven or SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark

These might be silly questions to ask but I am stuck and not able start my Spark projects. I have never done it before so bear with me.

I have a Linux Machine (RHEL) where I have installed Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8. Set up the paths for Spark and Scala. I am able to run `spark-shell` command and Scala REPL in the terminal. I am not using Hadoop and running Spark in local mode.

Now I have to start my project, so after writing the code how can I build it. I can't use Eclipse or any IDE for that matter. I need to do it without it. For Maven and for SBT also, there might be some issues. So is there any way where I can have my jars downloaded offline and then put up somewhere so that I can build my code.

Also, I have a jars folder in Spark installation folder, what is that for?

What is `spark-submit` used for? Is it used for building or just running the built code?

I went through the documentation but I just got lost. I understand it might be a generalized question so let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this questions shouldn't be answered because it is too board and it's off topic - since it is not related with an specific programming problem.

However I will try to answer it just because I have been there.

> "have a Linux Machine (RHEL) where I have installed Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8. Set up the paths for Spark and Scala. I am able to run spark-shell command and Scala REPL".

Note that Spark includes its own Scala, so you don't need to install. Nevertheless, having a Scala RELP can help to try little code snippets that don't need Spark.

> "Now I have to start my project, so after writing the code how can I build it. I can't use Eclipse or any IDE for that matter. I need to do it without it. For Maven and for SBT also, there might be some issues".

I can understand not having an IDE in a server, but a build tool?
Anyways, if you can't install nothing there for any reasons *(like security or keeping the environment clean)* I think the best thing to do would be to program the Spark app in your personal computer, compile it there and upload the generated JAR to the server for running only.
Note that you can compile it manually using scalac... but that will be a nightmare.

> "Also, I have a jars folder in Spark installation folder, what is that for?"

When you start a Spark application *(like the spark-shell)* you will se a message like the following.
`WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.`
It means, that if you don't specify which jars to load, it will only use the ones inside that folder - it includes all the libraries Spark needs to run *(like the Scala standard library itself)*.
For your own apps, you may need dependencies, like for example the Spark-Mongo-Connector. For including those libraries when running your app you have a couple of options.

1. Create a **Fat JAR** with all its dependencies. However, keep in mind that you must exclude Spark and the Scala standard library from the generated JAR, since that can cause binary incompatibility problems.
2. Download all the JARs you need to a directory in your cluster, and pass them to  `spark-submit` using the `--jars` option.
3. Like the second one, but instead of passing every jar *(which can be many)*, create one **Fat JAR** but only for your dependencies instead.
4. Add the JARs to the the above folder, that will make them available to every spark app.

> "What is spark-submit used for? Is it used for building or just running the built code?"

It is used to launch an Spark App to the cluster, for Java/Scala you need to provide the JAR, for Python/R you provide the Script file(s).